# Issue using INNER JOIN on multiple tables in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, join, inner-join

I am trying to create a new table by using inner join to combine multiple tables. All, the tables have a primary key/column called `reach_id`. I have a primary table called `q3_studies`. I want all of the columns from this table. I then have multiple other tables that have `reach_id` + `another column`. I want to JOIN this table ON `reach_id` that matches `q3_studies` but only include the other columns (so I don't have redundant `reach_id` columns). My first attempt seems to work if I run it from `SELECT * ...` using a `LIMIT 1000;` at the end, but adds redundant `reach_id`s.

```
SELECT * FROM second_schema.q3_studies s
INNER JOIN second_schema.bs_trigger_q3 b ON s.reach_id = b.reach_id
INNER JOIN second_schema.mod_unmod_q3 m ON s.reach_id = m.reach_id LIMIT 1000;
```

How can I amend this to add only the additional columns (ex: bs_trigger_q3 has an additional columns called `bs_trigger`, `mod_unmod_q3` has an additional column called `mod_unmod`)?

Secondly, if I try to create a new table, I get an error: `column reach_id specified more than one.` What am I doing wrong here?

```
CREATE TABLE first_schema.report_q3 AS
SELECT * FROM second_schema.q3_studies s
INNER JOIN second_schema.bs_trigger_q3 b ON s.reach_id = b.reach_id
INNER JOIN second_schema.mod_unmod_q3 m ON s.reach_id = m.reach_id;
```

Comment: Ask 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question. PS JOIN ON inputs 2 tables each with an alias (possibly implicitly taken from a base table name) & outputs a result with a column for every left input table column then a column for every right input table column.  SELECT \* then keeps them all. For alias A, SELECT A.* returns just the associated table's columns. If you don't want them all, why are you using SELECT \*? (Rhetorical.) SELECT the ones you want. (Read a tutorial & the manual for functionality you are using.)

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. [ask] [Help]

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask], [Help] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `select *` you need to list the columns you want explicitly. This is good practice in any case. It also allows you to rename columns e.g. `s.column_A as "foo_column"`

In the future the schema may change.

```
CREATE TABLE first_schema.report_q3 AS
SELECT 
  s.reach_id, 
  s.column_A, s.column_B, 
  b.column_C, b.column_D,
  m.column_E, m.column_F
FROM second_schema.q2_studies s
INNER JOIN second_schema.bs_trigger_q3 b ON s.reach_id = b.reach_id
INNER JOIN second_schema.mod_unmod_q3 m ON s.reach_id = m.reach_id
;
```

If your editor does not help you with column names consider a different editor.

Comment: Yep, removing the * was key and worked perfectly.